# Adicionar elementos html com Javascript utilizando loop

Tags: javascript

Olá,
Através de um `objeto`, eu preciso criar elementos `HTML` utilizando o `loop` do Javascript.

No código de exemplo, e conforme o print, percebo que ao adicionar os batches `(lotes)`, também é adicionado um item `undefined`.

Bom, eu só preciso exibir os contratos como se fossem uma lista, e para cada contrato, adicionar os respectivos lotes em um `dropdown list (select option)`, pois depois, irei exibir as faturas em outra lista de acordo com o lote selecionado.

**código de exemplo**

```html
<div id="div-contracts"></div>
<style>
#div-contracts {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
.loren {
    float:left;
    width: 45px;
}
.ipsulum {
    float:left;
    width: 35%;
}
</style>


<script>
let object = {
    name: 'wagner',
    contracts: [
        {
            id: 1,
            contract: '123',
            batches: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    batch: '1',
                    invoices: [
                        {
                            value: 10,
                            due: '01/01/2020',
                        },
                        {
                            value: 10,
                            due: '01/02/2020',
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    batch: '2',
                    invoices: [
                        {
                            value: 10,
                            due: '01/04/2020',
                        },
                        {
                            value: 10,
                            due: '01/05/2020',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            contract: '456',
            batches: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    batch: '1',
                    invoices: [
                        {
                            value: 15,
                            due: '01/01/2020',
                        },
                        {
                            value: 14,
                            due: '01/02/2020',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
};

let getById = (id, parent) => parent ? parent.getElementById(id) : getById(id, document);
const DOM =  {
    contract: getById('div-contracts'),
};

function htmlForBatchsOptions(contract) {
    let batchOptions;
    for (const batch of contract.batches) {            
        batchOptions += `<option value="${batch.id}">${batch.batch}</option>`;
    }
    return batchOptions;
    //return document.querySelector('select.sel-batch').innerHTML = batchOptions;
};

for (const contract of object.contracts) {
    DOM.contract.innerHTML +=
    `<div class="contract">
        <div class="loren">
            <span>${contract.contract}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ipsulum">
            <select class="sel-batch">
                ${htmlForBatchsOptions(contract)}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>`;
}
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para resolver os problemas de undefined inicie a variável com valor vazio antes de concatena-la:

let batchOptions = '';

Comment: Outra sugestão é:

utilizar o onchange no select:
<select class="sel-batch" onchange="getInvoices(this)">

Pegar o id selecionado para encontrar o batche selecionado:
function getInvoices(selectObject){
  var value = selectObject.value;  
}

O restante acho que você consegue dar sequencia.

Comment: Então, carregar as faturas(invoices) assim que a página é carregada, até consigo; dentro do loop eu, adicionei o filter `let batchFilteredByContractId = contract.batches.filter(batch => batch.id === 1);`
E depois tenho acesso as faturas relacionadas ao lote.
Agora estou realmente com dificuldades em carregar as faturas(invoices) do lote (batch) selecionado, outra coisa que tenho dificuldade, é que preciso criar um evento para clicar no contrato e carregar todos os dados relacionados ao contrato que cliquei!